# In the reactive-state engine, how can I generate a unique UUID for each row of the result table?

Tags: database, dolphindb

I generate uuid in this method:

```py
<rand(uuid(), 1)[0]>
```

I found that the output UUID for each row are the same if the data inserts into the reactive-state engine at the same time.
If I use <rand(uuid(), TradeTime.size())>, it prompts me the “size” function cannot be used here.

```py
createEngine() => Can't use aggregate function [size] in metrics for reactive state engine.
```

Answer (score 0):

The custom function is as follows:

```py
def genUuid(x){ 
   return rand(uuid(), x.size()) 
}
```

However, the uuid randomly generated by this method has been used for a long time and cannot be guaranteed to be unique.